# How to output iterating resulting from for-loop?

Tags: c#, xml, for-loop

I am trying to get my function to output xml but the function keeps returning a null value.  I have tried debugging the **string a** and **string b**.

`String a = Illiquidity option, credit model minted, Pricing service unveiled`

`String b = <p>…</p>, <p>…</p>, <p>…</p>`

Please advice where I maybe going wrong.  Thanks.

```
public  string articleXMLTest()
{
    string a = testtitle();
    string b = testStory();
    string c = "";
    string results = "";

    string[] aA = a.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string[] bA = b.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (aA.Length == bA.Length)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < aA.Length; i++)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;

            XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "gb2312", string.Empty),
                new XElement("article",
                new XElement("status", "Approved"),
                new XElement("title", aA[i].ToString()),
                new XElement("subtitle", aA[i].ToString()),
                new XElement("synopsis", bA[i].ToString() + "..."),
                new XElement("url", c),
                new XElement("display_date", dt.ToShortDateString())
            ));

            results  = results  + Environment.NewLine + doc.ToString();
        }          
    }
    return results;           
}
```

Comment: interesting, this code works for me... how do you manage to get `null` as return value? Even if the Arrays don't have the same length you would get an empty string

Comment: @HimBromBeere it is not obsolete, the compiler would complain, but it doesn't. It closes `new XElement("article",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks ok for me. As this code is working the only possibility I can imagine is the return sitting outside of your `if` which will return `null` if your length's arnt matching.

Go this way and check your output again:

```
public string articleXMLTest()
{
    string a = testtitle();
    string b = testStory();
    string c = "";
    string results = "";

    // Debug the length of your arrays. Im pretty sure they wont match.
    string[] aA = a.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string[] bA = b.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (aA.Length == bA.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < aA.Length; i++)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;

            XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "gb2312", string.Empty),
                new XElement("article",
                new XElement("status", "Approved"),
                new XElement("title", aA[i].ToString()),
                new XElement("subtitle", aA[i].ToString()),
                new XElement("synopsis", bA[i].ToString() + "..."),
                new XElement("url", c),
                new XElement("display_date", dt.ToShortDateString())
            ));

            results = results + Environment.NewLine + doc.ToString();
        }
        // Or set a breakpoint here to check if it reaches this return.
        return results;
    }
    // I guess you will end up here.
    return "Length of aA isnt matching length of bA";
}
```

**Problem:**

`String b = <p>…</p>, <p>…</p>, <p>…</p>`
Your `...` parts will have some commas too.

**Solution:**

For `b` use this one to split:

```
Regex rgxPTag = new Regex("<p>(.*?)<\\/p>");
string[] bA = rgxPTag.Matches(test).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

If you need the `<p>` tags aswell:

```
Regex rgxPTag = new Regex("(<p>.*?<\\/p>)");
string[] bA = rgxPTag.Matches(test).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

**Notice:**

If there are line-breaks between `<p>` and `</p>` you'll need to define `SingleLineMode` for the regex to work:

```
Regex rgxPTag = new Regex("...", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Hi, yes that's correct.  I didn't notice this before.  Sorry.  How can i parse the `string b`?  Any further guide would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: @user3070072 Do you need the `<p>` and `</p>` parts after the split or just the content?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply.  Yes, i do need the <p>  and </p> and the content inside of the `<p>  and </p>`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code it does work. Maybe there appears any kind of exception which you do not handle.

E.g. the arrays `aA` and `bA` have not the same length.